# how i change result text view position from top left to any other location?

Tags: android

just tell me how i change text view position in this code? in this app  application show result textview at top left  position of application how to i change is position to botton center or right side i try layout position in xml but is always show on top left result barcode value  on same location where button present and button overlap resultText view value s o how can i change textview position?????

```
     package com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo;

   import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.Vector;

    import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
   import com.google.zxing.Result;


  import com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.camera.CameraManager;
  import com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.decoding.CaptureActivityHandler;
  import com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.decoding.InactivityTimer;
  import com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view.ViewfinderView;

  import android.R.string;
 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
  import android.os.Vibrator;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

   public class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
private boolean hasSurface;
private Vector<BarcodeFormat> decodeFormats;
private String characterSet;
    public static TextView txtResult;
private InactivityTimer inactivityTimer;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private boolean playBeep;
private static final float BEEP_VOLUME = 0.10f;
private boolean vibrate;
private static String barCode;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //³õÊ¼»¯ CameraManager
    CameraManager.init(getApplication());

    viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
    txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v)

        {
            Toast.makeText(CaptureActivity.this,""+barCode, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    hasSurface = false;
    inactivityTimer = new InactivityTimer(this);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    if (hasSurface) {
        initCamera(surfaceHolder);
    } else {
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
    decodeFormats = null;
    characterSet = null;

    playBeep = true;
    AudioManager audioService = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioService.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
        playBeep = false;
    }
    initBeepSound();
    vibrate = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.quitSynchronously();
        handler = null;
    }
    CameraManager.get().closeDriver();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    inactivityTimer.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        CameraManager.get().openDriver(surfaceHolder);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return;
    }
    if (handler == null) {
        handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeFormats,
                characterSet);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!hasSurface) {
        hasSurface = true;
        initCamera(holder);
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;

}

public ViewfinderView getViewfinderView() {
    return viewfinderView;
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public void drawViewfinder() {
    viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();

}

public void handleDecode(Result obj, Bitmap barcode) {
    inactivityTimer.onActivity();
    viewfinderView.drawResultBitmap(barcode);
     playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
    txtResult.setText(obj.getBarcodeFormat().toString() + ":"
            + obj.getText());


    barCode=obj.getText().toString();

    //TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult2);
    //t.setText("SEcond code here"+barCode);    
}

private void initBeepSound() {
    if (playBeep && mediaPlayer == null) {
        // The volume on STREAM_SYSTEM is not adjustable, and users 
    found      it
        // too loud,
        // so we now play on the music stream.
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(beepListener);

        AssetFileDescriptor file = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                R.raw.beep);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(),
                    file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());
            file.close();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(BEEP_VOLUME, BEEP_VOLUME);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}

private static final long VIBRATE_DURATION = 200L;

private void playBeepSoundAndVibrate() {
    if (playBeep && mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (vibrate) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);
    }
}

/**
 * When the beep has finished playing, rewind to queue up another one.
 */
private final OnCompletionListener beepListener = new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    }
};

  }


   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview_view"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



   <com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view.ViewfinderView
  android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:background="@color/transparent"/>


   <TextView android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"  
        android:text="hello"      
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"


    android:text="Button" />





     </FrameLayout>







  package com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view;

   import com.google.zxing.ResultPoint;
   import com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.R;
   import com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.camera.CameraManager;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
  import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.View;

 import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.HashSet;

 /**
  * This view is overlaid on top of the camera preview. It adds the viewfinder   
  rectangle and partial
  * transparency outside it, as well as the laser scanner animation and result points.
  *
 * @author dswitkin@google.com (Daniel Switkin)
 */
    public final class ViewfinderView extends View {

     private static final int[] SCANNER_ALPHA = {0, 64, 128, 192, 255, 192, 128, 64};
   private static final long ANIMATION_DELAY = 100L;
   private static final int OPAQUE = 0xFF;

  private final Paint paint;
  private Bitmap resultBitmap;
   private final int maskColor;
  private final int resultColor;
  private final int frameColor;
  private final int laserColor;
  private final int resultPointColor;
  private int scannerAlpha;
   private Collection<ResultPoint> possibleResultPoints;
   private Collection<ResultPoint> lastPossibleResultPoints;

  // This constructor is used when the class is built from an XML resource.
  public ViewfinderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);

// Initialize these once for performance rather than calling them every time in    
 onDraw().
 paint = new Paint();
 Resources resources = getResources();
 maskColor = resources.getColor(R.color.viewfinder_mask);
 resultColor = resources.getColor(R.color.result_view);
 frameColor = resources.getColor(R.color.viewfinder_frame);
 laserColor = resources.getColor(R.color.viewfinder_laser);
 resultPointColor = resources.getColor(R.color.possible_result_points);
 scannerAlpha = 0;
 possibleResultPoints = new HashSet<ResultPoint>(5);
 }

 @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 Rect frame = CameraManager.get().getFramingRect();
 if (frame == null) {
  return;
 }
 int width = canvas.getWidth();
 int height = canvas.getHeight();

 // Draw the exterior (i.e. outside the framing rect) darkened
 paint.setColor(resultBitmap != null ? resultColor : maskColor);
 canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, frame.top, paint);
 canvas.drawRect(0, frame.top, frame.left, frame.bottom + 1, paint);
canvas.drawRect(frame.right + 1, frame.top, width, frame.bottom + 1, paint);
canvas.drawRect(0, frame.bottom + 1, width, height, paint);

 if (resultBitmap != null) {
  // Draw the opaque result bitmap over the scanning rectangle
  paint.setAlpha(OPAQUE);
  canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, frame.left, frame.top, paint);
 } else {

  // Draw a two pixel solid black border inside the framing rect
  paint.setColor(frameColor);
  canvas.drawRect(frame.left, frame.top, frame.right + 1, frame.top + 2, paint);
  canvas.drawRect(frame.left, frame.top + 2, frame.left + 2, frame.bottom - 1, paint);
  canvas.drawRect(frame.right - 1, frame.top, frame.right + 1, frame.bottom - 1, 
  paint);
  canvas.drawRect(frame.left, frame.bottom - 1, frame.right + 1, frame.bottom + 1, 
   paint);

  // Draw a red "laser scanner" line through the middle to show decoding is active
  paint.setColor(laserColor);
  paint.setAlpha(SCANNER_ALPHA[scannerAlpha]);
  scannerAlpha = (scannerAlpha + 1) % SCANNER_ALPHA.length;
  int middle = frame.height() / 2 + frame.top;
  canvas.drawRect(frame.left + 2, middle - 1, frame.right - 1, middle + 2, paint);

  Collection<ResultPoint> currentPossible = possibleResultPoints;
  Collection<ResultPoint> currentLast = lastPossibleResultPoints;
  if (currentPossible.isEmpty()) {
    lastPossibleResultPoints = null;
  } else {
    possibleResultPoints = new HashSet<ResultPoint>(5);
    lastPossibleResultPoints = currentPossible;
    paint.setAlpha(OPAQUE);
    paint.setColor(resultPointColor);
    for (ResultPoint point : currentPossible) {
      canvas.drawCircle(frame.left + point.getX(), frame.top + point.getY(), 6.0f, 
    paint);
    }
  }
  if (currentLast != null) {
    paint.setAlpha(OPAQUE / 2);
    paint.setColor(resultPointColor);
    for (ResultPoint point : currentLast) {
      canvas.drawCircle(frame.left + point.getX(), frame.top + point.getY(), 3.0f, 
  paint);
    }
  }

  // Request another update at the animation interval, but only repaint the laser line,
  // not the entire viewfinder mask.
  postInvalidateDelayed(ANIMATION_DELAY, frame.left, frame.top, frame.right,  
 frame.bottom);
 }
 }

  public void drawViewfinder() {
 resultBitmap = null;
 invalidate();
  }

 /**
  * Draw a bitmap with the result points highlighted instead of the live scanning 
  display.
*
 * @param barcode An image of the decoded barcode.
*/
 public void drawResultBitmap(Bitmap barcode) {
 resultBitmap = barcode;
 invalidate();
 }

  public void addPossibleResultPoint(ResultPoint point) {
   possibleResultPoints.add(point);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute android:gravity in XML like this :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

Or if you want to change programmatically, use this :

myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

Answer (score 1):

if your textView has fill_parent in layout params @Deepanker Chaudhary's solution is right.
but your textView has wrap_content like sizes in layoutparams you should use margins.